Finding the Noether current
I'm currently reading "QFT for the gifted Amateur by Lancaster and Blundell, and in a lot of the problems I'm a bit unsure of how to do them, an example asked

"Consider a system characterized by $N$ fields $\phi_1, ... ,\phi_N$. The Lagrangian density is then $$\mathcal{L}(\phi_1, ... ,\phi_N;\partial_\mu \phi_1, ... , \partial_\mu \phi_N;x^\mu).$$ Show that the Noether current is
$$J^\mu = \Sigma_a \Pi^\mu _a D\phi^a - W^\mu (x)$$
where $D\mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu W^\mu$.

I then looked up an answer and tried to follow along, but there were some things that didn't make much sense. I'll link to the answer and if somebody can explain the math for the second and third equality in the Lagrangian variation I would be very thankful!
https://zachary-harris.grad.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2765/2019/10/Chapter-10-Symmetry.pdf (Question 10.2)

Do you mean the second and third equality in $\delta \mathcal{L}$?

Yes, that's what I'm confused about.

I will try to show the derivation step by step.
Since $L$ is a function of $\psi$ and $\partial \psi$, for the definition of partial, we have
$$\delta L = \frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial {\psi _a}}}\delta {\psi _a} + \frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a}).\tag1$$
Use the product rule for partial derivatives:
$${\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta {\psi _a}) = {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}})\delta {\psi _a} + \frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}{\partial _\mu }\delta {\psi _a}.$$
As the partial and the delta would not affect each other, we could exchange them, so
$$\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a}) = \frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}{\partial _\mu }\delta {\psi _a} = {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta {\psi _a}) - {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}})\delta {\psi _a}.$$
Put it in (1), we get
$$\delta L = (\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial {\psi _a}}} - {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}))\delta {\psi _a} +{\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta {\psi _a}).$$
If $\delta L$ satisfied the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion,we have
$$\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial {\psi _a}}} - {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}})=0.$$
So
$$\delta L = {\partial _\mu }(\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial ({\partial _\mu }{\psi _a})}}\delta {\psi _a}).$$

Thanks! I should probably keep all the partial derivative rules in my mind when I do other questions like this.
